# Weighted shift Operators

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I was given a paper by Allan L. Shields on Weighted Shift operators and Analytic Function Theory, American Mathematical Society.

On the very first page, the definition of Weighted Shift operator is defined as follows,

> 1. **Introduction.** A weighted shift operator $T$ on (complex) Hilbert
>    space $H$ is an operator that maps each vector in some orthonormal basis $\{e_n \}$ into a scalar multiple of the next vector
>    $$Te_n= w_n e_{n+1}$$
>    for all n.

My problem is, what if $H $ is finite dimensional, how would one define the weighted shift operator on $H$.

Secondly, I don't understand the proof of **PROPOSITION 1** as stated in the attachment below. I would so much appreciate if someone help me, give hints or recommend a text. Thank You

[image]

Comment: The proof is direct computation; the conjugate of $U$ sends $e_n$ into $\bar{\lambda_n}e_n$ and the lambdas have unit modulus means $U$ unitary trivially; in the finite dimensional case the last base vector gets send to $0$  as the unilateral shift is a partial isometry but not unitary. The references given (Helson, Hoffman) are excellent with applications to the Hardy spaces (there is a famous theorem that characterizes the unilateral shift there in terms of inner functions, and another classical for the bilateral shift in terms of sets of positive measure)